# Fancybox v3.5.7: how can enable mobile close click outside?

Tags: javascript

I need help with fancybox v3.5 mobile close click outside,

// Clicked on the slide
clickSlide: "close",

```
// Clicked on the background (backdrop) element;
// if you have not changed the layout, then most likely you need to use \`clickSlide\` option
clickOutside: "close",

// Same as previous two, but for double click
dblclickContent: false,
dblclickSlide: false,
dblclickOutside: false,

// Custom options when mobile device is detected
// =============================================

mobile: {
  preventCaptionOverlap: false,
  idleTime: false,
  clickContent: function (current, event) {
    return current.type === "image" ? "toggleControls" : false;
  },
  clickSlide: function (current, event) {
    return current.type === "image" ? "toggleControls" : "close";
  },
  dblclickContent: function (current, event) {
    return current.type === "image" ? "zoom" : false;
  },
  dblclickSlide: function (current, event) {
    return current.type === "image" ? "zoom" : false;
  }
},
```

Im try add closeClickOutside= true
dosnt work for me